# How to solve Kivy's 'AttributeError'?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I'm creating an app using KivyMD.

The main.py file has two classes:

```py
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget 

class Button_Functions (Widget):
  def function1 (self):
    # is called by tapping a certain button

class App (MDApp):
  def build (self):
    return Builder.load_file("screen.kv") 

App().run()
```

The screen.kv file is structured as follows:

```css
MDScreen:
  MDBoxLayout:
    Widget1:
    Widget2:
    Widget3: 

<Widget1@MDBoxLayout>:
  ...
<Widget2@MDGridLayout>:
  ...
<Widget3@MDBoxLayout>:
  MDRaisedButton:
    text: "Raised Button"
    on_press: root.function1()
```

The problem occurs when I try to press the button to call function1, then I get the error "AttributeError: 'Widget3' object has no attribute 'function1'".

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Isn't this as expected ? You are calling `function1` in `Widget3` (in screen.kv) but defined that in `Button_Functions` (in main py) (which seems to be completely different). Try changing the name 
 `Button_Functions` with `Widget3`.

Comment: Even if you do that you may have some problem (or `Warning`) with that renamed class (it seems, the dynamic class has been subclassed both in .kv and .py).

Comment: Didn't know the class needed to have the same name as the widget. The only problem that occurred with this change was with the widget's `size-hint` property, but then I changed `class Widget3 (Widget)` to `class Widget3 (BoxLayout)` and then it went back to normal. Thanks for the help.

Comment: If you want to mean this literally : *'the class needed to have the same name as the widget'*, this might not be obvious. You can rename `Widget3` with any valid identifier (say, `MyContainer` etc.), but that name should be consistent throughout the code (whether in `kivy` or `python`.) Also note that, re-declaration of the same dynamic class (derived from same superclass) both in .kv and .py may raise `Warning` in Logs.

Comment: I understand now.